# Javascript: How to consolidate/Transform multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need help with transforming multidimensional array in javascript.
Example input array:

```
[
[['a',1],['b',2],['c',3]],
[['a',4],['d',2],['c',3],['x',5]],
[['a',1],['c',2],['f',3],['x',1],['o',7]]
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
["a",1,4,1],
["b",2,null,null],
["c",3,3,2],
["d",null,2,null],
["x",null,5,1],
["f",null,null,3],
["o",null,null,7]]
]
```

So I need to merge part of the array on first element, and fill the gaps with "null".
e.g. pair with "x" has value 5 and 1 in second and third row, so it should look like this ["x",null,5,1].
Just to explain the data, every line is a charting data series after optimization, maintaining correct position of the values is crucial.

So far, I merged the data to the expected format, but can not figure out how to add the "null" values on the correct position.

Here is my code:

```
var cubes = [
        [['a',1],['b',2],['c',3]],
        [['a',4],['d',2],['c',3],['x',5]],
        [['a',1],['c',2],['f',3],['x',1],['o',7]]
        ];
var out = [];
for (var i=0; i<cubes.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<cubes[i].length; j++) {
        out.push(cubes[i][j]);
        for (var x=0; x<out.length-1; x++) {
         if (out[x][0] == cubes[i][j][0]) {
            out[x].push(cubes[i][j][1]);
            out.pop();
         }
        }
    }
}
console.log(out);
```

This gives me following output:

```
[
["a",1,4,1],
["b",2],
["c",3,3,2],
["d",2],
["x",5,1],
["f",3],
["o",7]
]
```

Also, I "feel" that there must be simpler way to achieve this, perhaps with map/reduce function, but my brain is today frozen :/
Any suggestions?

[JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/3mzg8yfo/5/)

Comment: You have a logic flaw in your concept already. You need to explicitly know maximum offset so that you can generate null padding: `null,null,7`. Or you need to make two runs algorithm, like those that generate console output with space padding.

Comment: You'd have to do a 2-pass logic. gather all the keys, sort them and then fill the array for the keys. thats the only way you can get nulls in the right order.

Comment: Oh he doesn't need two pass for left padding. But right padding must be added in second pass.

Comment: And of course, my solution is the fastest, because you also don't need any temporary objects... http://jsperf.com/33240307/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted an easy way, so here's demonstration of JavaScript's newest shortcuts for array operations:

```js
    var test = [
      [['a',1],['b',2],['c',3]],
      [['a',4],['d',2],['c',3],['x',5]],
      [['a',1],['c',2],['f',3],['x',1],['o',7]]
    ];
    var result = [];
    // This value will be updated to max possible value count
    var max_values = 0;
    
    // Every row in input
    test.forEach(function(row, index) {// Index is used to properly pad null from right
      //Every couple letter, number
      row.forEach(function(cell) {//cell is one of ['x', 0]
        var groupName = cell[0]; //a, b, c ...
        // Find a group in results
        var entry = result.find(function(newRow) {
          return newRow[0] == groupName;
        });
        // If no group was found, create a group and add it to results
        if(!entry) {
            entry = [groupName];
            result.push(entry);
        }
        // Left-pad nulls
        while(entry.length-1<index)
            entry.push(null);
        // Finally push the value
        var count = entry.push(cell[1]);
        // Update max count number
        max_values = Math.max(max_values, count);
      });
    });
    // Second pass - fill in `null` so that all entries are the same length
    result.forEach(function(row) {
      // Push until all rows are as long as the longest one
      while(row.length<max_values)
        row.push(null);
    });
    //Debug
    console.log(result);
    document.write("<pre>"+result.join("\n")+"</pre>");
```

Featuring: **[.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** and **[.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)**. Note that `find` is really new and neither `find` neither `forEach` appear in older frowsers.

#### [I win!](http://jsperf.com/33240307)

Comment: @dave If I write "*here's demonstration of JavaScript's newest shortcuts for array operations* why do you expect it to work in EI? I intentionally wrote this using new technologies to demonstrate them. But fear not, if I rewrite this to `for` loops approach, it will be even faster, but much less readable.

Comment: BTW, IE is [being deprecated](http://www.infoq.com/news/2015/03/relacing-IE), so it's less technically valid than my functions.

Comment: Hi guys, wow - some competition going on here! :)
Just to explain the "sorting" question, sorting by keys is indeed fine, and I see this as a bonus as I planned to add it later. What I meant by maintaining correct position of values was actually having the values within rows in correct order. This is fulfilled by all solutions.

Getting back to this solution, I like the fact it is well commented. I need to look at it a bit further over the weekend, but having comments, speed :) and learning about the "find" in Javascript validates this solution as winner for me.
Thank you!

Comment: @Markus btw [mdn has polyfill for find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) if you want to support older browsers. Naturally, polyfill will be a little slower than a native function.

Answer (score 1):

I'd build a temporary object to store your arrays by key, then loop through that object to build your final result.

```js
var index = 0;
var result = [];
var temp = {};
var cubes = [
  [['a',1],['b',2],['c',3]],
  [['a',4],['d',2],['c',3],['x',5]],
  [['a',1],['c',2],['f',3],['x',1],['o',7]]
];

for(var i = 0; i < cubes.length; i++) {
  var row = cubes[i];
  row.forEach(function(item) {
    var name = item[0];
    var value = item[1];
    
    if (!temp[name]) {
      temp[name] = {
        index: index, //store index to guarantee same order in result
        values: new Array(cubes.length)
      };
      index++;
    }
    
    temp[name]['values'][i] = value;
  });
}

for(var name in temp) {
  var a = [];
  a.push(name);
  for(var i = 0; i < cubes.length; i++) {
    if (temp[name]['values'][i])
      a.push(temp[name]['values'][i]);
    else
      a.push(null);
  }
  result[temp[name].index] = a;
}

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Temporary object is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Following requires sorting of the main keys and therefore final results are sorted the same

```
var keys = [];
// sort cubes and create array of `keys`
cubes.forEach(function(cube){
    cube.sort(function(a,b){
       return a[0] > b[0] ;
    }).forEach(function(subArr){
        if(keys.indexOf(subArr[0]) ==-1 ){
            keys.push(subArr[0]);
        }
    });
});
// sort keys
keys.sort();
// map new array based on sorted cubes and sorted keys
var out = keys.map(function(key, idx){
    var newArr = [key];

    cubes.forEach(function(cube){
        var match = cube.filter(function(subArr){
            return subArr[0] === key;
        });
        newArr.push( match.length ? match[0][1] : null)
    });

    return newArr

});
```

Produces:

```
[    
    [ "a", 1, 4, 1 ]
    [ "b", 2, null, null ]
    [ "c", 3, 3, 2 ]
    [ "d", null, 2, null ]
    [ "f", null, null, 3 ]
    [ "o", null, null, 7 ]
    [ "x", null, 5, 1 ]    
]
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wmm29b53/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: I think he wants the result in the same order that it appears in the original arrays, i.e. `a, b, c, d, x, f, o`.

Comment: @dave hard to say what really determines output order. OP never replied when asked

Comment: Sorting is not needed, it just slows down the process.

Comment: Thank you for excellent example on using "map". Although I picked the Tomas solution, I like yours as well! 
And sorting is what I was thinking to add later therefore very valid solution for me as well.